# Issue with sap.ui.mdc.FilterField and DateTime data type

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm facing an issue filtering a DateTime field using sap.ui.mdc.FilterField and dataType sap.ui.model.type.DateTime.

My files are very similar to the official FilterBar sample provided here: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.ui.mdc/sample/sap.ui.mdc.demokit.sample.TableFilterBarJson/code

But here are the specifics:

My FilterField in the main XML view looks like this:

```
<mdc:FilterField
    delegate="{name: 'sap/ui/mdc/field/FieldBaseDelegate'}"
    label="{i18n>createdOn}"
    propertyKey="created_on"
    dataType="sap.ui.model.type.DateTime"
    conditions="{$filters>/conditions/created_on}"
    maxConditions="1" />
```

My PropertyInfo configuration is as follows:

```
{
    name: "created_on",
    label: i18nModel.getProperty("createdOn"),
    visible: true,
    path: "created_on",
    dataType: "sap.ui.model.type.DateTime",
    formatOptions: {
        source: {
            pattern: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss X',
        },
        UTC: true,
        style: 'medium'
    },
    maxConditions: 1
}
```

My JSONModel (retrieved from a PHP backend) bound to the table is structured like this:

```
[{"created_on":"2023-11-04T18:17:03+0100"}]
```

The date is correctly displayed in the table column, the FilterField valueHelp shows a calendar for selecting the date and time, and the selected value is correctly applied to the FilterField.

However, when I apply the filter, no rows are returned, not even the ones that should match the filter criteria.

I've tried several things, such as changing the pattern and adding format options directly in the FilterField tag within the XML view, among others.

Could you help me initiate a new 'investigation' into this issue? Even if we try some things I've already attempted, it would help to 'check' them off as non-working solutions.

Thanks!